# Sitecore logging exception

Tags: iis-7.5, sitecore, sitecore6

I recently began working with Sitecore on a fresh system. I installed IIS, configured it, and was able to get the project to build and load on IIS just fine. While trying to figure out why the startup time was so slow, it began to give me this error.

```
 Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: message
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: message

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: message]
   Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info(String message, Object owner) +309
   Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule.Init(HttpApplication app) +557
   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +530
   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state, MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +304
   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +404
   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr appContext) +475

[HttpException (0x80004005): Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: message]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +12966756
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +159
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +12806561
```

I have tried the following:

- Doing a full get (overriding all) for TFS and re-building
- Pulling down an exact copy of the files that are on the dev environment (which works)
- Disabling logging in Sitecore
- Deleting the project from my local system and pulling it down again from TFS, rebuilding
- Deleting the inetpub www folder IIS was pointing to and re-building
- Removing and re-adding the IIS site and app pool
- Uninstalling IIS and reinstalling it
- Deleting temporary ASP.NET files from the .NET framework folders
- Clearing out IIS config files (along with a reinstall)
- Clearing out .NET machine.config files and repairing .NET
- Re-registering .NET with IIS
- Changing the app pool user
- Granting very liberal permissions to the inetpub folder, .NET framework folders (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET...)
- Adding the app pool user to Performance Log Users, Performance Monitor Users
- Removing all config files from /App_Config/Include/

I'm not sure what else to try at this point.

Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you have a config issue somewhere. I would start by replacing the web.config and everything in `/App_Config` from the downloadable zip on SDN and then deploy your code back over that again. If you're still having issues, also delete everything from `/bin`, replace from zip and re-deploy

Comment: I don't believe this is the case. Copying the files from the dev environment (which is functioning fine) doesn't have any effect--it still gives the error. If it were a configuration issue either dev would be broken too or an exact copy would work fine locally.

Comment: I replaced the web config with the stock Sitecore 6.6 webconfig, cleared out `/App_Config/Include` and updated the other `/App_Config` files to defaults. No improvement :(

Answer (score 0):

One of the first things that Sitecore does is to start writing out a message that says "HttpModule is being initialized". Before you get the exception, do you see this message in the logs? The exception you have seems to indicate that initial loadup is trying to extract details for the message to log but is not receiving any.

If you examine your log file, you should hopefully be able to see how far the logging can get before it is getting a 'null' message and blowing up. From there, it will be easier to identify what the next typical information line would be and track down what is happening.

For example, here is a typical 6.6 INFO block from the start of a log file:

```
10024 10:26:13 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized
10024 10:26:13 INFO  
10024 10:26:13 INFO  **********************************************************************
10024 10:26:13 INFO  **********************************************************************
10024 10:26:13 INFO  Sitecore started
10024 10:26:13 INFO  Sitecore.NET 6.6.0 (rev. 130529)
10024 10:26:13 INFO  
10024 10:26:13 INFO  C:\Src\TFS\Path\Website\bin\Sitecore.Client.dll (Sitecore CMS, Sitecore Client Application, 6.6.0 rev. 130529)
10024 10:26:13 INFO  C:\Src\TFS\Path\Website\bin\Sitecore.Kernel.dll (Sitecore CMS, Sitecore CMS Kernel Library, 6.6.0 rev. 130529)
10024 10:26:13 INFO  C:\Src\TFS\Path\Website\bin\Sitecore.Nexus.dll (Sitecore.Nexus)
10024 10:26:13 INFO  
10024 10:26:13 INFO  Operating system Microsoft Windows NT 6.1.7601 Service Pack 1
10024 10:26:13 INFO  
10024 10:26:13 INFO  Microsoft.NET version 4.0.30319.18444
10024 10:26:13 INFO  
10024 10:26:13 INFO  Process id: 12132
10024 10:26:13 INFO  Windows identity used by the process: IIS APPPOOL\MyAppPoolUser. Impersonation: True
10024 10:26:13 INFO  Managed pipeline mode: Integrated
10024 10:26:13 INFO  
10024 10:26:13 INFO  EventQueues enabled: False
10024 10:26:13 INFO  Instance Name:MyInstanceName
10024 10:26:13 INFO  
10024 10:26:13 INFO  Threshold settings
10024 10:26:13 INFO    Show threshold warnings: False
10024 10:26:13 INFO  
10024 10:26:13 INFO  Databases
10024 10:26:13 INFO    core
10024 10:26:13 INFO    master
10024 10:26:13 INFO    web
10024 10:26:13 INFO    filesystem
10024 10:26:13 INFO  
10024 10:26:13 INFO  Domains
10024 10:26:13 INFO  Heartbeat - Initializing
10024 10:26:13 INFO  Heartbeat - Interval set to: 00:00:02
10024 10:26:13 INFO  Heartbeat - Worker thread started
10024 10:26:13 INFO  Trying to load XML configuration /App_Config/Security/Domains.config
10024 10:26:13 INFO    sitecore
10024 10:26:13 INFO    extranet
10024 10:26:13 INFO    default
10024 10:26:13 INFO  **********************************************************************
10024 10:26:13 INFO  **********************************************************************
10024 10:26:13 INFO  Attempting to get ASP.NET process history
10024 10:26:13 WARN  No process history available
```

Comment: Jay, unfortunately no log file is created (despite all logging settings being turned on). I also do not get an elmah. Log files are generated on dev and were generated locally before this started.

Comment: Then the next thing might just be to do as @jammykam suggests and try to get a clean install of Sitecore running on your box. If that works, then you can start looking at diffs between the clean version of Sitecore and your build. You may be missing a necessary include file or DLL.

Comment: Ooh it did generate some logs through additional attempts. This is all that is put: (this but 3 times)

`2552 14:15:38 WARN  Counter category 'Sitecore.System' does not exist on this server.`

Comment: You might want to make sure you have logging turned all the way up (i.e. INFO or DEBUG) to make sure you are seeing everything. If the first message you get is a warning, that might indicate your logging level isn't high enough to see all the messages

Comment: Also, that particular error would indicate that the Sitecore counters are being requested by the application, but are not available.

Comment: At least that indicates the site is trying to load. Counters not being installed is to be expected if you did not use the exe installer but you can [install them manually](http://www.sitecore.net/unitedkingdom/Community/Technical-Blogs/Shelley-Benhoff/Posts/2011/12/Troubleshooting-Sitecore-Performance-Counters.aspx)

Comment: If you are truly stuck and think it is a Sitecore issue then I would download the exe and install a clean copy of Sitecore. It should rule out everything else (IIS, database, permissions) and then step by step add your solution (first the database, check content is there, then code base).